# PhpStorm configure Xdebug with Docker

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

Our project environment configured by Docker and program language is PHP.
I want configure the Xdebug to debug the program.

Because the code mapping to the dockers, and runtime environment on the Docker, I can't configure the xdebug directly.

Now, I meet some questions:

This is web service validation shot, it has 2 warnings:

[image: This is Web service validation shot, it has 2 warning]

This is php.ini with Xdebug:

[image: This is php.ini configuration about Xdebug]

This is Xdebug log:

[image: This is xdebug_log]

The service name is correct. How do I do?

Comment: So far it looks like xdebug config was added to the wrong php.ini. Double check that.

Comment: I double check the php.ini from local and docker environment,and confirm the xdebug.remote_enable=1 configure correctly.Like the second pic show

Comment: I was referring more about IP and xdebug port -- they are different between pic #2 and #3... unless you have changed them later or something...